# Plotting x_n = A**n * x0 in python

Tags: python, matrix, matrix-multiplication

I'm trying to plot a matrix multiplication in python. 
I have the matrix `A = [[0,-1],[1,1.6]]`, and `x0 = [[5],[-1]]`.
The task is to plot `xn`, when I know that `xn = A**n * x0`, for `n = 1, ... ,30`
This is my code so far:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 30
A = np.matrix([[0,-1],[1,1.6]])
xn = np.zeros(n)
x0 = np.matrix([[5],[-1]])
for i in range(n):
    xn[i]= A**i*x0
    plt.plot(xn)
plt.show()
```

I keep getting the value error: setting an array element with a sequence, and when it works I get a really strange plot, which is probably wrong. Any ideas on how to do it?

Comment: What did you expect the plot to look like?

Comment: I'm not sure, but not it just plots alot of straight lines, and the question is "what curve do you think xn lies on", so something tells me I'm supposed to get a curve out, but maybe I'm reading it wrong

Comment: You should first think about what you are trying to do before writing some random code.

Comment: I mean, to be fair, I'm here because I don't understand what I'm supposed to do and need help. Really a beginner to python, and the task is to plot A**n * x0, which I'm not sure how to do.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you want to take the matrix to a power by multiplying it by itself or by exponentiating the numbers inside of it. In any case, the reason why your code is throwing a `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.` is because the matrix vector multiplication `A**i * x0` returns an array of length two - i.e. a vector.

Maybe you want to plot the vectors that result from the matrix-vector product. In that case, this code should do the trick:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

n = 30
A = np.matrix([[0,-1],[1,1.6]])
xn = np.zeros((n, 2))
x0 = np.matrix([[5],[-1]])
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i in range(n):
    A = A @ A
    xn[i, :] = np.squeeze(np.dot(A, x0))
    ax.plot([0, xn[i, 0]], [0, xn[i, 1]])
    label = r"$A^{%i}$" % (i+1)
    ax.annotate(label, xy=(xn[i, 0], xn[i, 1]))
plt.show()
```

Notice I changed the shape of xn - it's now (nx2) compared to n as in your code. This means the result of the matrix-vector product will fit into xn. The `@` notation indicates matrix multiply in python3. I also labeled the line in the resulting plot with the power the matrix was taken to. You can see the output vector changing direction as the matrix changes. I think this is a nice example of how matrices (especially 2x2) can be thought of as linear transformations when applied to vectors. This video explains that concept nicely: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kYB8IZa5AuE.

Comment: Thanks alot, this helped!